# Is using a cached "this" faster than "this" when accessing methods of the same object?

Tags: javascript, performance

if I access this.something multiple times from another method, would it be faster to cache "this" and access something() or should I just use this.something() over and over?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Foo = (function() {
    return {
        something: function() {
            // Do something
        },
        stuff: function(obj) {
            this.something(obj);
            // ...
            this.something(obj);

            /* OR should I cache this? */
            var $that = this;
            $that.something(obj);
            // ...
            $that.something(obj);
        }
    };
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Check *CMS'* comment below for the **real truth** (but I don't think it changes anything regarding performance).

---

**Approximate truth:**

No, it won't make any difference. Upon execution of the function, an *activation object* is created and put at the beginning of the scope chain of the function (more specifically, its execution context).

The activation object has the properties `this`, `arguments`, one property for each parameter passed and for each variable declared in the function.

Hence, `this` and `$that` live in the same scope and you gain nothing from it. You only get an improvement, when you reference an object/value locally that is in a higher scope.

```
  +-------------------+     +-------------+
  | Execution Context |  +->| Scope Chain |
  | ----------------- |  |  | ----------- |
  | Scope chain  +----+--+  | 0    |  +---+----------+
  +-------------------+     | 1    |  +---+-...      |
                            +-------------+          |
                                                     |
                                                     |
                                                     |
                            +--------------------+   |
                            |  Activation Object |<--+
                            | ------------------ |
                            | this     |  foo    |  (if called with foo.method())
                            | arguments|[someObj]|
                            | obj      | someObj |
                            | $that    |  foo    | (undefined until assignment)
                            +--------------------+
```

Graphic stolen from [***High Performance JavaScript***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X). It's an interesting book to read.

Comment: Look at you, gettin' all fancy with the diagrams. ;o) +1

Comment: Great! Can I borrow *(have)* some money?

Comment: Don't believe everything that you read on books (specially JS books ;) this time Zakas got it wrong ;), `this` is not technically a *property of the activation object*, although the concept is strongly related with the current execution context. In ES5, each [execution context](http://j.mp/gz2m2C) has a *State Component* called `ThisBinding`, however it isn't really a *property* as `arguments` and other identifiers declared in that scope are. `this` is just a [Keyword](http://j.mp/ib0WJ3) that evaluates to the value of the `ThisBinding` component of the current execution context.

Comment: @CMS: Uhh, shame on Zakas... and on me :D But I put so much effort in the graphic :(

Comment: @Felix hehe, in overall it is a good book, I liked it, this is just one of the technical nitpicks that maybe only ECMASCript-addicts care about ;)

Comment: @CMS: Doesn't this change depending on browser implementation? Newer modern browsers compile javascript to bytecode and JITs the shit out of it, while older browsers interprets javascript - those engines must have different ways of working - I know that ECMA is a standard, but lets get real, nobody follows it more than loosely :P

Comment: @Martin: Thing is that we can't have much of a conversation without something observable. That's what the ECMAScript standard provides. It's not unreasonable to reference the standard *as though* it is accurately implemented, unless we have some particular knowledge about an implementation that deviates in a manner relevant to the question posed. If it was a discussion about *named function expressions* I'm certain @CMS and @Felix would have given a standard based answer with the relevant caveats that apply to IE's implementation for example. :o)

Answer (score 3):

You'll just be pointing at a copy of a reference to an object, rather than directly to the reference to the object. I can't imagine how caching it would be faster - but hey, fire up a test framework, execute it inside a loop 10000 times and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Benchmarking it is the only valid way to determine performance impact, yes. But in cases like these, I'm willing to bet that it won't make any (noticeable) difference. (A different issue I have with this approach: Even if it's "25% faster", it won't make any noticeable difference in 99.99% of all code).

Comment: I'd be willing to bet my paycheck this won't make any difference. I also should have specified multiple runs...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why a variable should be faster than `this`.

Something that could have been possibly faster but that I found does NOT work is to cache the whole method lookup... e.g. by doing `m = object.method; ... m(x,y,z);`. This is something that for example in Python works (because of the bound method concept) but that however is not available in Javascript.

The result of a method lookup in Javascript gives you more or less something like what is a method pointer of C++, in other words a function that doesn't know `this` and so you must provide `this` yourself it to be able to call it.

The only difference is that in C++ any method that's not declared static will not be callable without providing a `this`, while in Javascript saving the method lookup may *apparently* work only for methods that at runtime don't need `this` perform as expected.

For example `var mycos = Math.cos; mycos(0.3);` on chrome at least apparently works because `cos` doesn't need to access Math (not really that surprising after all).

You can get a closure that functionally works as a cached method...

```
var cachedfoo = obj.foo;
var foo = function(x, y, z) { return cachedfoo.call(obj, x, y, z); }
...
foo(1,2,3); // this is the same as obj.foo(1,2,3)
```

that could be useful for other reasons, but that IMO it's not going to be faster (it would probably be *slower* indeed)...

Comment: You can cache the method, but you need to use `.call()` or `.apply()` to set the proper value of `this` for the method (assuming `this` is used in the method you're calling).

Comment: Not having to specify "this" is exactly what the concept of a bound method is about. Avoiding the lookup of the method but adding the lookup of "call" is not that interesting (call and apply are probably there for reasons different from speed). Something like `foo = function(x, y, z){return cachedfoo.call(object,x,y,z);}` is not going to be a big win for speed IMO :-)

Comment: That's a good point. It is just replacing one property lookup with another. Main point was that you most certainly can reference a function and call it. To use the example in your answer `m = object.method; ... m(x,y,z);` would work. Only difference is that *if* the method being called relies on `this`, you'd need to do `m = object.method; ... m.call(this,x,y,z);` :o)

Comment: I don't mean to be tedious with my comments, but I'd imagine your update would actually be slower. Each time `foo` is invoked you're creating 2 execution contexts, still doing the property lookup of `.call()` and  also having to follow the scope chain to find `obj`. This is because `cachedfoo.call(obj, x, y, z)` is evaluated each time `foo` is invoked instead of being evaluated once when the function is assigned to `foo`. ES5 has a `.bind()` method that could eliminate much of this. Overall, your point is absolutely correct that you won't experience performance gains by caching `this`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Only profiling will answer here. But before doing such micro-optimizations, ask yourself if you really need to.